# Unable to import RocksDB module

Tags: python, rocksdb

I am fairly new to working with RocksDB. I have set up the environment for RocksDB following the [link here](https://youtu.be/7PX_H00V6RA), but when I run a sample Python script having `import rocksdb` it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "`<string>`", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rocksdb'
```

Can anybody suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: is you python file name `rocksdb`?

Comment: It seems you should install `rocksdb` module, either [this](https://pypi.org/project/python-rocksdb/) one or [this](https://pypi.org/project/pyrocksdb/).

Comment: I tried doing both @PetrVytovtov

Comment: python -c 'import rocksdb; print ("works!")'
I try executing a simple line like this on the console.